# Clustering Loop Confusion

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

My basic setup I have using the `cluster` module is: (I have 6 cores)

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
  }
}else{
//Code here
  console.time("Time: ");
  var obj = {'abcdef' : 1, 'qqq' : 13, '19' : [1, 2, 3, 4]};
  for(var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  console.timeEnd("Time: ");
}
```

If I were to run that test.
It will output:

[image]

But... if I run that same exact test inside the `cluster.isMaster` block, it will output:
[image]

1) Why is my code being executed multiple times instead of once?

2) Since I have 6 `cpu cores` helping me run that test, shouldn't it run that code only once but perform the operation faster?

Comment: A given piece of Javascript such as your `for` loop is only going to run on one particular cluster.  Clustering is used to run multiple operations (such as multiple incoming http requests) each in its own cluster so thet separate requests can run in parallel on separate cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're forking `os.cpus().length` *separate* processes. So if `os.cpus().length === 6`, then you should see 6 separate outputs (which is the case from the output you've posted).
2. No, that's not how it works. Each process would be scheduled on a separate core. It's not about running it faster, but being able to do *more* processing in *parallel*.

Comment: 'processing in parallel', that helps a lot.  So with that said, if I have a global  loop that is running every 2 seconds (its part of my game), it will essentially be running 6 times every 2 seconds? This might be beyond the scope, but my loop iterates over a LARGE object and manipulates it (deletes, and sends data via websockets, etc), it would be a good idea to not have that loop in a fork, right?

Comment: JSON parsing isn't something that's really parallelizable, unless you can somehow split up the work between all of the cores/workers (which is unlikely since node's clustering uses JSON to communicate between master and worker, so it'd end up just getting re-stringified and re-parsed, which is a waste). In any case, you should always test different scenarios to see if using workers *actually* improves performance or not.

Comment: yeah, I just cannot wrap my head around running my global loop 6 times every 2 seconds instead of just every 2 seconds. It just seems like it would increase load, not improve performance. Maybe I'll do some testing and get back to SO with other questions.